# Affect all but one image with CSS code

Tags: html, css, image

I'm looking to affect all but one (maybe two) images on my website. I', having a little trouble figuring it out.

Is there some sort of code I add to not affect certain images please?

Here Is the code i'm currently using:

```
// IMAGE 5 STYLING
#collection-56aa7c3422482efd63ae16e1, #collection-

56aa841e5dc6de4554608778, #collection-55b98395e4b08fff340c1e65,
#collection-5807e5edf7e0abd4e55c38bb{
.sqs-block-image .image-block-wrapper {
height: 150px !important;
width: 150px !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
padding-bottom: 0px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
border-radius: 300px !important;
transition: all ease-in-out 600ms !important;
    img {
      height: 150px !important;
      width: 150px !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      left: 0 !important;
      top: 0 !important;
      border-radius: 300px !important;
    }
}
.image-caption {
text-align: center;
margin-left: 0px !important;
}
.image-caption p strong {
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #555 !important;
color: #555 !important;
border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
padding-bottom: 10px;
transition: all ease-in-out 600ms !important;
}
  .sqs-block-image:hover {
  .image-block-wrapper {
 -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg) !important;
    -moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(10deg);}
.image-caption strong {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
  }}
// END OF IMAGE 5 STYLING
```

Thank you for your help :)

Sophie.

Comment: What effect are you looking for?  Does your page have HTML or is it a pure CSS site?

Comment: Why couldn't you create a certain class for the images you want to change and leaving that class out for the ones you do not want to change?

Comment: Hi there - Thanks for replying to my post - I believe it's a CSS code: http://www.thedistancelive.com/kind-words << the images turn into circles and rotate.. I would like for all but one image (the image right at the bottom of the page) to be normal, and not affected by the code.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Hi Thomas Byy, I'm very new to coding, sorry i should have mentioned this in my post :)

Comment: Unfortunately, saying repeatedly that you are new to coding won't help us help you. instead, look up how to use CSS classes. It's all you need for this.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do it would be a css selector `img:not(.not-affected-img)` and add the `.not-affected-img` class to the images that shouldn't be affected.

Although you should actually add a class to the changing images:

```
.image-effect:hover {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

Comment: Hi Gabriela, Thanks for your reply :) 

Could you walk me through this please?, I'm sorry Im completely new to this.. 

Sophie x

Comment: In your html you should add the class to the images you want to affect:
`<img src="someimage.png" class="image-effect" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:not() CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to not include an element. For example:

```
img:not(.dontselect) {
  // styles for all imgs EXCEPT .dontselect
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply - I;m very new to coding so please bear with my uneducated questions.. How would i target the specific image please? and when i have where would i put this into the code ?

Comment: @SophieJones No problem; you would put this into your CSS styles and to target the specific image, you would need to have a way to identify it, such as its ID. Before the :not(), you need to put all of the elements you want to select, such as img, and inside the parentheses, you need to put the element(s) that you don't want to apply style to, such as #imageID. Hope that helped.